How to change Pivot position when applying Curve Modifier?
I've been having problems with my object pivots, every time I apply Curve Modifiers, the pivot randomize its position. This really complicates my animation process, is there a way to center the pivot to the geometry mesh in object mode?
I leave you guys a print of my project:



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Done!! The file is now downloadable

I do not know what you mean by "the pivot randomize its position". The Transform Pivot Point is set to Bounding Box which in Object Mode is the origin of the object. You have disabled the display of origins in your viewpoort so you might not know where they are: the objects have their origin about +1.336 m in local Z direction of their parent object "Carrusel". When you apply the Curve modifier, the origin is exactly there and that is where the pivot point is.
